# Prove Inverses not need be Unique if Associativity fails

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M=\{x, y, z\}$ be a set and let $\circ$ be a binary operation on $M$ such that the identity element is $x$ and $y \circ y = x = y \circ z$. Prove that inverses need not be unique if associativity fails given the multiplication table below.

$x \circ x = x, x \circ y = y, x \circ z = z$

$y \circ x = y, y \circ y = x, y \circ z = x$

$z \circ x = z, z \circ y = x, z \circ z = x$

Comment: What does the problem ask you to do?

Comment: "Explain why the result of $y$ having two different inverses for $\circ$ does not contradict the theorem on the uniqueness of inverses." Sorry if that wasn't clear in the main post, I'll edit it.

Comment: You should at least leave the multiplication table in, so that the multiplication results I use in my answer don't look so magical :) (how did I know that $y \cdot z = x$?)

Comment: Er, I think I'll use the preview function more to make these things clearer. Thanks for your help again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associativity fails if you consider $ y \cdot z \cdot z$. We have $ (y \cdot z)\cdot z = x \cdot z = z$, but on the other hand $ y \cdot (z \cdot z) = y \cdot x = y$. So this is not a group, and inverses need not be unique.

Comment: Thanks so much! And wow, I'm bad. I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Yeah, that thing is really far from a group. I don't see the point of the question. It should be more like. Prove inverses need not be unique if associativity fails.

Comment: @TryingToLearn your question was terribly misleading.

Comment: I didn't realize the way you phrased the problem was actually what I should have been attempting to do. In the future I won't post such a long ramble and I'll try to keep things more concise and to the point. Thanks for being kind with me!

Comment: It looks like the point of this exercise was precisely to provide you with an example where "inverses need not be unique if associativity fails". But understandably, it's hard to state it in those terms if you don't know what exactly the exercise was meant to teach you - and of course, you can't be expected to figure out the point of the exercise without having solved it! Feel free to update your question title, but don't worry about it too much.